# Android Style Background color of all Fragments

Tags: android, layout, styles

I have an app that uses a bottom navigation bar with a nav_host_fragment. I want to set the background color of the nav_host_fragment to have a background color (without changing the color of the bottom navigation bar). I've tried setting the nav_host_fragment background directly and through styles but none of those worked

Here is what I tried (in all possible combinations)

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/green</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/green</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/green</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Styles.xml file is used for whole app theme. if you want to show separate color on particular component, change it in declared file